# Java regular expression to match that a string contains one or more characters whose ASCII value is between 0-31 and 127-159?

Tags: java, regex

How to write a Java program using regular expression to match that a string contains one or more characters whose ASCII value is between 0-31 and 127-159?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is an impossible question, as ASCII values are only defined in the range 0 to 127. There is no such thing as an ASCII value of 128 to 159.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Values from 128 - 255 are Extended ASCII http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/american-standard-code-information-interchange/ascii-codes-table.png

Answer (score 1):

You're wanting ASCII values from 0 - 31 (0x00 - 0x1F) and ASCII Value 127 (0x7F), then extended ASCII values from 128 - 159 (0x9f)

I found these two patterns to work

```
"[\\x00-\\x1F\\x7F\\x80-\\x9F]+"
```

or

```
"[\\p{Cntrl}\\x80-\\x9F]+"
```

`\\p{Cntrl}` means `[\\x00-\\x1F\\x7F]`

Sample Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String string = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= 31; i++) {
            string += (char)i;
        }

        for (int i = 127; i <= 159; i++) {
            string += (char)i;
        }

        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[\\p{Cntrl}\\x80-\\x9F]+").matcher(string);
        if(m.matches()) {
            System.out.println("We have a match");
        } else {
            System.out.println("We have no match");
        }
    }
```

Results:

> We have a match

Reference http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

```
[\x00-\x1E,\x7F-\x9F]+
```

That should work